# Let : $f(x)=\log_3(\sqrt{4-x}+81), \ \ g(x)=3^{x-2}+1$

Tags: functions, logarithms

Let : $f(x)=\log_3(\sqrt{4-x}+81), \ \ g(x)=3^{x-2}+1$

And: $g(a)=f^{-1}(b)  \ \ \ \ ,f(b)=g^{-1}(c)$

Then : $a+b+c=?$

My try:$g(a)=3^{a-2}+1=4-(3^b-81)^2$
How next?

Comment: How exactly you equated $3^{a-2}+1=4-(3^b-81)^2$?

Comment: @ItiShree.$f(x)=\log_3(\sqrt{4-x}+81)$ So $x=4-(3^y-81)^2$

Comment: Okay thanks for elaborating @atbhatia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an assumption that $a$, $b$, $c$ are real?

If $a$, $b$, $c$ are real, then $b=f(g(a))=\log_3(\sqrt{4-g(a)}+81)\ge4$. However, $f(b)=\log_3(\sqrt{4-b}+81)$. As $c=g(f(b)$, $c$ is well-defined if and only if $b\le 4$.

Therefore, $b=4$. It is easy to see that $a=3$ and $c=10$.

Answer (score 0):

you must derive the inverse functions,e.g. $$y=3^{x-2}+1$$ the inverse function is given by
$$y-1=3^{x-2}$$
$$\log_3(y-2)=x-2$$
$$x=2+\log_3(y-1)$$
can you finish?
and
$$3^y=\sqrt{4-x}+81$$
$$(3^y-81)^2=4-x$$
...

Comment: I know it . but next, I cannot :(

Comment: (-1) This misses completely the exercise.